# Unitary time evolution operator for hamiltonian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, hamiltonian

I have homework, which I've seen solution with which I have some problem.

The homework is to find time evolution of state $|\psi(t)\rangle$, if the hamiltonian of the state is $\hat{\textbf{H}}=\epsilon \hat{\textbf{P}} $, where $\hat{\textbf{P}}$ is projection operator and $\epsilon$ some energy dim constant.

So, we can begin with equation
$$ |\psi(t)\rangle = \hat{\textbf{U}}|\psi(0)\rangle,$$
where $\hat{\textbf{U}}=\mathrm{e}^{-it\hat{\textbf{H}}}$.

Then we can write
$$
\hat{\textbf{U}}|\psi(0)\rangle = \mathrm{e}^{-it\hat{\textbf{H}}} |\psi(0)\rangle = 
\mathrm{e}^{-it\epsilon\hat{\textbf{P}}} |\psi(0)\rangle = 
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}(it\epsilon\hat{\textbf{P}})^n\right)|\psi(0)\rangle = 
 \left[ \hat{1} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}(it\epsilon)^n \hat{\textbf{P}}  \right] |\psi(0)\rangle = 
\left[\hat{1}+ \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}(it\epsilon)^n + \hat{1} - \hat{1} \right) \hat{\textbf{P}}\right]|\psi(0)\rangle =
\left[\hat{1}+ \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}(it\epsilon)^n  - \hat{1} \right) \hat{\textbf{P}}\right]|\psi(0)\rangle = 
\left[\hat{1}- \hat{\textbf{P}} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}(it\epsilon)^n \hat{\textbf{P}}\right]|\psi(0)\rangle =
\left[\hat{\textbf{Q}} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}(it\epsilon)^n \hat{\textbf{P}}\right]|\psi(0)\rangle = 
\left[\hat{\textbf{Q}} + \hat{\textbf{P}} \mathrm{e}^{i\epsilon t}  \right]|\psi(0)\rangle.
$$

And ok, I understand i mathematically, but I don't get why we can't end this lot earlier like here
$$
\hat{\textbf{U}}|\psi(0)\rangle = \mathrm{e}^{-it\hat{\textbf{H}}} |\psi(0)\rangle = 
\mathrm{e}^{-it\epsilon\hat{\textbf{P}}} |\psi(0)\rangle = 
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}(it\epsilon\hat{\textbf{P}})^n\right)|\psi(0)\rangle = 
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}(it\epsilon)^n\hat{\textbf{P}}\right)|\psi(0)\rangle =
\hat{\textbf{P}}\mathrm{e}^{i\epsilon t} |\psi(0)\rangle.
 $$

Is this something with index? I have to first rewrite sum to get rid of $\hat{\textbf{P}} = \hat{1}$ and then pull out $\hat{\textbf{P}}$ from sum and then minus unitary operator?

Answer (score 5):

Note that $\hat{\mathbf{P}}^n = \hat{\mathbf{P}}$ only holds if $n\neq 0$, so your manipulation is incorrect.  You need to extract the $n=0$ case before you replace $\hat{\mathbf P}^n$ with $\hat{\mathbf P}$, which is why the additional steps in the correct solution are required.